*ctx.bumps.get("pool") Giving Error
I am trying to create a simpleswap contract.
My lib.rs code is:
#[program]
pub mod solana_swap {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize_pool(ctx: Context<InitializePool>) -> Result<()> {
        instructions::initialize_pool(ctx)
    }
}

My state.rs:
#[account]
pub struct Pool {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub bump: u8,
    // Other fields if needed
}

impl Pool {
    pub const LEN: usize = 8 + // Discriminator
        32 + // authority
        1; // bump
}

And a instructions.rs:
use crate::errors::SwapError;
use crate::state::Pool;
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializePool<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = payer, space = Pool::LEN)]
    pub pool: Account<'info, Pool>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

pub fn initialize_pool(ctx: Context<InitializePool>) -> Result<()> {
    let pool = &mut ctx.accounts.pool;
    pool.authority = ctx.accounts.payer.key();
    pool.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("pool").ok_or(SwapError::BumpNotFound)?;

    Ok(())
}

Problem is,
anchor build is giving the error:
pool.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("pool").ok_or(SwapError::BumpNotFound)?;
   |                  ----------^^^--------
   |                  |         |
   |                  |         this is an associated function, not a method

I found somewhere that the command changed since anchor 0.29.0, but I don't know exactly what to do.
Also, the documentations online are pretty outdated too. If possible, please let me know a good documentation as well.

You are right, this changed in newer anchor versions.
You can now directly access the bump like this:
let bump: u8 = ctx.bumps.pool;


Thank you very much
